# Display objects in collections one per each line in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

If I do `User.where(active: false)` in the Rails console, the result is hard to parse.

Is there any trick without iteration (besides gems) to output each value/object one per line?

Comment: `pp User.where(active: false)` it will print each object from new line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As part of [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826491/display-objects-in-collections-one-per-each-line-in-console/25826572#comment40403489_25826491), I am adding an answer here so that other programmers can get help.

You can use `pp` while using rails console to get presentable print. E.g.:

```
pp User.where(active: false)
```

It will print every object on a new line.